# Proving that $\frac{1}{2} \le \frac{1}{2^n+1} + \frac{1}{2^n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n + 2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble proving that:
$$\frac{1}{2} \le \frac{1}{2^n+1} + \frac{1}{2^n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n + 2^n}$$

***Edit: The next step is actually a mistake. I've put up a comment to the accepted answer explaining why it's a mistake.***

I've tried reducing every single fraction on the right side to $\frac{1}{2^n + 2^n}$, but then I get result:
$$\frac{1}{2} \le \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}{2}$$
which is not true.

I also tried to put this harmonic sequence in Wolfram Alpha and it tells me it equals $\ln(2)$, which is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: There's $2^n$ summands, each of which is at least $\frac1{2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is what I where I started from induction. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $\;1\le k\le 2^n\;$ we have that

$$\frac1{2^n+k}\ge\frac1{2^n+2^n}=\frac1{2^{n+1}}\;,\;\;\text{so:}$$

$$\underbrace{\frac1{2^n+1}+\ldots+\frac1{2^n+2^n}}_{2^n\;\text{summands}}\ge\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}=\frac12$$

Comment: Ah, so that's where I made a terrible mistake. For some reason I thought there is a total of $2^n - 1$ summands. Now it makes perfect sense. thanks.